# Reading dynamically generated textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating textboxes dynamically in JavaScript but when I try to console log the (before passing them in array to ajax post) I only get `undefined`. I tried searching the web for how to do it, but nothing seemed be a "hit".

Here is the essential parts.

```
//textbox naming convention is "id"+intlaskubox and I can read them like 
textbox = document.getElementById("id2");

//amount of textboxes generated
var generated = intlaskubox;
console.log(generated);

//this is ok (I can get the value of the box)
textbox = document.getElementById("id" + generated);
console.log(textbox.value);


// (here I get undefined times the amount of boxes generated)
var i = 0;
while (i < generated) {
    cu[i] = document.getElementById("id" + i);
    console.log(cu[i].value);

    i++;
}
```

I have tried Firebug and normal console log, but it seems I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the HTML? And your loop should be `i <= generated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you forgotten to initialize the array `c`? Try this:

```
var i = 1, c = [],generated=5,inputRes=document.getElementById("res");
while (i <= generated) {
    c[i] = document.getElementById("id" + i);
    inputRes.value+=c[i].value;    
    i++;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/5w7qcwag/)

Comment: Yes, indeed I had forgotten, but now I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null 199:660myFunction 199:660onclick 199:814

Comment: Still do not undestand why, if I can read it in the previoud example

Comment: does a checkbox with id "id0" exists?

Comment: Yes I am an idiot. Thanks for pointing that out :) I changed the integer to start at 1 and that solved it

Answer (score 0):

because value not set in DOM

you change like this

```
while (i < generated ) {
          cu[i] = document.getElementById("id"+i);
          console.log(cu[i].getAttribute("value"));

            i++;
        }
```